# How change detection works on string, array and object declared in an Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm asking this question to better understand how change detection works in Angular.

I know I should use `RxJS` to notify components when a variable declared in a service changes.

What I'm interested is why Angular detects a change on an array and object, but not on string variable.

Here is an example

Service changes a string, array and object after 3 seconds

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class NameService {
  name = '';
  list = [];
  obj = {
    a: 'something'
  };

  constructor() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.name = 'Name changed';
      this.list.push('a', 'b');
      this.obj.a = 'obj.a changed';
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { NameService } from './name.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <div>{{name}}</div>
      <div>{{list | json }}</div>
      <div>{{obj | json }}</div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = '';
  list = [];
  obj = {};

  constructor(private nameService: NameService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.name = this.nameService.name;
    this.list = this.nameService.list;
    this.obj = this.nameService.obj;

  }
}
```

`list` and `obj` changes are detected by Angular but not `name`. Does this happen because arrays and objects are mutable and strings are immutable?

You can play with code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ch-detec-jzm6r1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple reason is that `this.list = this.nameService.list;` and `this.obj = this.nameService.obj;` are assigning the left hand side a reference (pointer) to an array or an object.

When content is added to the array or changes are made to the value on an object, it is the content of the array/object that are changing rather than the pointer to the list or object, which in this case, is what has been assigned to `this.list` and `this.obj`.

On the other hand, `this.name = this.nameService.name;` is assigning the exact value of to this.name.

**So how is changes in data being propagated?**

The `ngOnInit()` [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) is called only once, when the component is created. It is at the point in time where the values on the service are copied to the variables within the component, which in your case is as follows.

```
this.name = this.nameService.name;  // The actual value is assigned to this.name
this.list = this.nameService.list;  // The pointer to the list in memory is assigned to this.list
this.obj = this.nameService.obj;    // The pointer to the object in memory is assigned to this.obj
```

When the `setTimeout` call back function is executed after 3 seconds,

1. The value of the `name` variable on the service is changed
2. The **content** of the list and object on the services are updated (note, that the pointer, the actual value retrieved when calling `this.nameService.list/obj` **remains the same**)
3. Angular is notified that an asynchronous event has happened (when setTimeout has been executed) and a change detection cycle is run.

Once the change the detection cycle is run, Angular re renders the content that it has.

In case of the `name` variable, it renders the static value. In case of the `list/obj` it reads the content of the list/object that the respective pointers (which reference has never changed since initialization) are pointing to and renders the new content (which is what has been updated).

**Updated:-**

This [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) provides an in depth application on how change detection works.